str,contains(patern) to write patter to df column
I have a data frame (df_bv_tikkie):



Omschrijving
IBAN_Tik




/TRTP/iDEAL/IBAN//BIC/ABNANL2A/NAME/name via Tikkie/REMI/00345346356 3253636 Tikkie NL30ABNA9999999991/EREF/11-07-2024 03:32 0031039140883718
None


SEPA Overboeking IBAN: BIC: NL30ABNA9999999992 Naam: AAB RETAIL INZ TIKKIE Omschrijving: Tikkie ID 390853985  1771
None



I am trying to extract the IBAN grom the 'Omschrijving' column and to write it into the 'IBAN_Tik' column.
The desired result is:



Omschrijving
IBAN_Tik




/TRTP/iDEAL/IBAN//BIC/ABNANL2A/NAME/name via Tikkie/REMI/00345346356 3253636 Tikkie NL30ABNA9999999991/EREF/11-07-2024 03:32 0031039140883718
NL30ABNA9999999991


SEPA Overboeking IBAN: BIC: NL30ABNA9999999992 Naam: AAB RETAIL INZ TIKKIE Omschrijving: Tikkie ID 390853985  1771
NL30ABNA9999999992



I have first tried:
import re
pattern = r'^NL[0-9]{2}[A-z0-9]{4}[0-9]{10}$'

df_bv_tikkie = df_bv_tikkie.reset_index()  
index_Omschrijving = df_bv_tikkie.columns.get_loc('Omschrijving')

df_bv_tikkie['IBAN_Tik'] = None

index_iban = df_bv_tikkie.columns.get_loc('IBAN_Tik')

for row in range(0, len(df_bv_tikkie)):
  iban = re.search(pattern, df_bv_tikkie.iat[row, index_Omschrijving])
  print(iban)
  df_bv_tikkie.iat[row, index_iban] = iban

This resulted only in None values in 'IBAN_Tik'
Then I tried
df_bv_tikkie['Omschrijving'].str.contains(pattern)

This also results in None values, as if the pattern is not recognised
However if I apply the pattern to a series
import re
pattern = r'^NL[0-9]{2}[A-z0-9]{4}[0-9]{10}$'

testiban2 = ['/TRTP/iDEAL/IBAN//BIC/ABNANL2A/NAME/name via Tikkie/REMI/00345346356 3253636 Tikkie NL30ABNA9999999991/EREF/11-07-2024 03:32 0031039140883718', 
'SEPA Overboeking IBAN: BIC: NL30ABNA9999999992 Naam: AAB RETAIL INZ TIKKIE Omschrijving: Tikkie ID 390853985  1771']



for x in testiban:
  result = re.search(pattern, x)
  if result:
    print(x)

this will print
NL30ABNA9999999991
NL30ABNA9999999992
--> suggesting that the pattern is accurate
so I don understand why my first two attempts do not recognise the pattern and or don print it to the column

testiban doesn't match testiban2, and if I fix that, the loop has no output. Please make a [mre]. It looks like the dataframe is not relevant to the problem and really you want to ask about the regex.

Oh, I just noticed the regex has anchors ^ and $. You don't want those in this case. In the future, making an MRE (like restarting from scratch) can help you catch basic mistakes like that.

^ and $ match the beginning and end of the string, so you should only use them if the column only contains an IBAN, not to match an IBAN in the middle of the text.

re.search() doesn't return a string, it returns an re_match object. I don't think you want to assign that in df_bv_tikkie.iat[row, index_iban] = iban. You should use .str.extract() to get the part of the string that matched the regexp.

BTW, if the dataframe were relevant to the problem, you should add the tag for the library (Pandas, Polars, Spark, etc).

You should remove the anchors ^ and $ from the regexp, since they restrict matches to the entire string, not a portion.
Then use .str.exctract() to get the part of the Omschrijving field that matches the pattern. Since this returns the parts of the string matching capture groups, you need to wrap the pattern in ().
pattern = r'(NL[0-9]{2}[A-z0-9]{4}[0-9]{10})'
df_bv_tikkie['IBAN_Tik'] = df_bv_tikkie['Omschrijving'].str.extract(pattern)

